# what does "withhold no sacrifice" mean?

Tags: american-english, british-english, speech

Reading Churchill's speech, I don't think I understand the following

"withhold no sacrifice, grudge no toil, seek no sordid gain", what does this statement mean?

Comment: What do you think it means?  Based on what you understand of the words, what part of it is confusing you?

Comment: "Withhold no sacrifice" can be rephrased as "Do not withhold any sacrifices". That is, to make any necessary sacrifices without holding back.

Comment: Context: "We shall [...] withhold no sacrifice, grudge no toil, seek no sordid gain, fear no foe." Does "We shall withhold no sacrifice." make sense?

Comment: Withhold no expense/sacrifice/acrimony/force/ill-will/computing resources/anger/what-else---- . You need to do your own homework on the word *withhold*.

Comment: For some perverse reason, English speakers like to phrase things negatively which they would probably be better off phrasing them positively. For example, "I'm not saying you don't have the talent to do great things, Bill" could just as easily have been phrased, "I'm saying you have the talent to do great things, Bill!" Phrasing things negatively can become a bad habit, though I'm sure there's a time and place for phrasing things negatively. IOW, it's a judgment call.

Comment: I understand with your detailed explanation, Thanks Eva!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. **withhold** verb: withhold; 3rd person present: withholds; past tense: withheld; past participle: withheld; gerund or present participle: withholding
>
> refuse to give
>
> 2. **sacrifice** noun: to offer, to offer up
> 3. **grudge** *verb*: 3rd person present: grudges; past tense: grudged; past participle: grudged; gerund or present participle: grudging
>
> be resentfully unwilling to give, grant, or allow (something).
>
> 3. **toil** *verb*: 3rd person present: toils; past tense: toiled; past participle: toiled; gerund or present participle: toiling
>
> work extremely hard or incessantly.
>
> "he grudged the work and time that the meeting involved"
>
> 4. **sordid** *adjective*:
>
> involving ignoble actions and motives; arousing moral distaste and contempt.
>
> 5. gain *verb*: 3rd person present: gains; past tense: gained; past participle: gained; gerund or present participle: gaining
>
> obtain or secure something desired, favorable, profitable, advantage
>
> 6. **gain** *noun*:; plural noun: gains
>
> an increase in wealth or resources.

*withhold no sacrifice = ***risk, offer, commit everything to the endeavor***

*grudge no toil = ***undertake all labor, effort involved, and do so willingly***

*seek no sordid gain = ***seek no cheap, ignoble, tawdry advantage***

**All definitions available at Google.com**